# How can I bind a boolean to the existence of a attribute in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

Is it possible to bind a boolean variable to the existence of a attribute?

```
 template: ...,
 host: {
   "[attr.disabled]": "disabled"
 }
```

This is rendered in the element as disabled="true" or disabled="false". But I want to use it in css with the [disabled] selector, that if the variable is **false**, the attribute **doesn't exist** and if **true** it does exist. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a boolean attribute to be removed the value needs to be `null` not `false`

```
 "[attr.disabled]": "disabled ? true : null"
```